# Accessing Global Window Object from MVC Razor and React Web Component

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, react-redux, razor-pages, web-component

We have a website which is a mix of .NET Razor pages and React Web Components.  There are a lot of user-input fields which require validation (e.g., only ASCII characters are allowed) and to handle this on the front-end I developed a JavaScript class to be used across all the Razor pages.  The class is in its own JavaScript file but is included in bundled (with other common functionality required across the site) which is loaded as soon as the user logins.

The same validation of input fields is also required in the React components and we are trying to find the best way to re-use the same JavaScript file so as to avoid duplicating code as making bug fixes/improvements simple to implement.  The library adds a global object to the `window` object as such:

```js
if (typeof (window) !== 'undefined' && typeof (window.CharacterHandler) === 'undefined') {
    window.CharacterHandler = new SpecialCharacterHandler();
}
```

which works great for the Razor pages but I can't seem to find a way to access it from the React Web Components.  Therefore:

1. Is there a way to access this same `CharacterHandler` object from the React Web Components?
2. If not, is creating a NPM package for the React part the only viable option?

Other developer suggestion was to deploy this file and then link to it.  However, there are many pages (Razor) and components (React) that require access to it so we would need to add the source link to many different places (e.g., all the partial pages) so we would prefer to avoid this.

This is the first time that I am working with a mixed site like this so if I am missing some obvious solution, please let me know.  I am open to additional suggestions for anything that would allow us to re-use this single file and reduce code duplication.  TIA.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by - React components cannot access this Class instance? All the global variables are accessible from React!